# Google Sheets - Use Script to Prevent Edits From Current User

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-permissions

I have made a script that will copy a template sheet, and allow the user to enter customer data. The entry sheet should have protected ranges to prevent edits to parts not needed for entry, for example headers, labels, cells with formulas, etc.

My issue is that it appears it is not possible for local script to remove edit permission for the current user, which is needed when the copy is made for a new entry. And I cannot figure out a way to "copy" permissions already set on the template. I have tried to set the script to remove by user email address, but the permissions will default to "can edit" for anyone that's not the administrator/owner.

I have been thinking of using a bit of script in web app format to do the trick, as web apps can be set to run as owner, however I'm not sure this is possible to lock the specific sheet, by calling a function from a web app script.

Any and all advise on this matter are extremely appreciated!

Comment: I'd go with a web app.  You have total control over what the user can do.

Comment: With a published web app you would generate HTML to show the user what they need to see, better organize the data, collect input and add it to the spreadsheet. It can run as you or as the individual if you are in a domain and you would still have more control. The later method allows you to control who can do what. Some people can accomplish one task and others a task. It also allows you to note who made a change by grabbing their login data. I have all of this working in a single web app where I have used spreadsheet tabs to mimic tables in a database, complete with one to many relationships.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the response! I'm fairly novice at programming in general, and not experienced in creating a web app. I would like to know, from your experience, is it possible to use a partial code (in this case the part for setting permissions) and publishing as a "web app" then have the spreadsheet script call the function in the web app? If so, that may be a simple way to work around this issue, and still let my people use the spreadsheet for data entry. (although I'd love to develop a fully operational web app in the future). Thanks again for your insight!